# Was Ultron having sympathy for Maximoff siblings or was he just using them to fulfill his own plans?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, I remember there was a scene in which Maximoff siblings tell Ultron about their past.

Though I don't exactly remember the details about how Ultron reacts. Moreover when Pietro dies, I dont think he shows any signs of remorse. (Or does he?)

Did Ultron really care about Pietro and Wanda or was he just using them to fulfill his own purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s complicated. Ultron sure was using the twins to fulfil his plans of dropping Sokovia and wiping out the human race. We know he was planning this all along from Vision’s dream when Wanda reads his mind.

> **Wanda Maximoff:** How could you?
>
> **Ultron:** How could I what?
>
> **Wanda Maximoff:** You said we would destroy the Avengers, make a better world.
>
> **Ultron:** It will be better.
>
> **Wanda Maximoff:** When everyone is dead.
>
> **Ultron:** That is not...! The human race will have every opportunity to improve.
>
> **Pietro Maximoff:** And if they don't?
>
> **Ultron:** Ask Noah.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

However, Ultron comes from the Mind Stone, Tony and Banner: he is an extremely clever AI. He has emotions and can display them as we see throughout the film. We see this quite clearly in the scene when Vision talks to the last Ultron and when Wanda rips the heart out of one of them.

It’s also worth noting that Vision is part Ultron. As we know Vision and Wanda have a very close relationship, romantic even. Whilst their journey together brought them closer I think the part of him that was Ultron might have played a part in it too.

Ultron certainly seems to care for the twins, especially Wanda. However, he also wanted his plan to come to fruition no matter what: he’s kind of like Thanos in that aspect. He wants to save the Earth (universe) no matter the personal cost to himself.

I think it’s worth noting though that we don’t know if Ultron would have saved Wanda and Pietro had they still been on his side at that point. He could have saved them by just keeping them in the air during the “meteor”.

Comment: As you mentioned, it does appear like the relationship similar to that of Thanos and Gamora

Comment: @user1170874 I wouldn't say their relationship is similar. It is Ultron's attitude towards saving the world that is similar to Thanos': they're both willing to sacrifice everything.

Comment: But imagine a scenario when Ultron is seeking the soul stone (to save the world ofcourse), it does come to my mind that he would sacrifice Wanda for it... more like Thanos... What do you think?

Comment: @user1170874 I'm sure he would, that's the point I'm making.

Comment: Oh sorry for my misunderstanding. And yes, Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

His **endgame** (get it?) was always to reforge the earth, eradicating humanity (them included) to make room for something better, probably his own creations. So it would be logical to say he didn't care or barely cared about them.